# How would you integrate the trignometric integral function Si(x)?

Tags: calculus, integration, functions, trigonometry, indefinite-integrals

The function Si(x) can be obtained when we integrate $\frac {sin(x)}x$.
But how would we go about integrating Si(x)?

More information about the function Si(x) can be found here https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trigonometric_integral

Comment: Do you mean $\mathrm{Si(x)}$ or $\mathrm{si(x)},$ they differ by $\tfrac{\pi}{2},$ and therefore the antiderivatives will differ by $\tfrac{\pi}{2}x.$

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This can be done analytically. You have
$$\DeclareMathOperator{\Si}{Si}
\int \Si(x)\,dx = x \Si(x) + \cos(x) + \text{constant}
$$
Test by differentiating the RHS:
$$
\frac{d}{dx} (x \Si(x) + \cos(x) + \text{constant}) = \Si(x) + x \frac{\sin x}{x} - \sin(x) = \Si(x)
$$
If you couldn't guess the result, you can get it by integrating by parts: 
$$
\int \Si(x)\,dx =\int 1 \cdot \Si(x)\,dx = x \Si(x) -  \int x \frac{\sin x}{x} = x \Si(x) + \cos x + \text{constant}
$$

Comment: I am still not clear on how you got your answer although differentiating it proves you've got the correct one

Comment: I just added it in the main text.

Comment: Got this but another question can come to my mind. How would we integrate (si(x))/x? It cant be done by integrating it by parts right?

Comment: Nvm I'll make another thread.

Comment: I don't see immediately how this could work out.